# Why is the contents of these objects not the same?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at this MDN [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) under the heading 'Prototype Mutation'.

I'm copying the code-snippets below into the console on my browser.

Why is `o1`:

**A**

```js
o1 = {}
let __proto__ = {color: "red"};

o1 = {__proto__};

console.log(o1);
```

Not the same as `o2`:

**B**

```js
o2 = {}

Object.setPrototypeOf(o2, {color: "red"});

console.log(o2);
```

I'm aware **A** is using shorthand property names.
Is `__proto__` a direct property on `o1`?

---

Edit: for one of the commenters to look at:

[image]

[image]

Comment: [This MDN page says it all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). You are colliding with a legacy property from `Object.prototype`. If you don't understand the prototype chain, you should read a tutorial about it (very important for javascript). To elaborate a bit, the difference is `o1.hasOwnProperty('__proto__') === true`, and `o2.hasOwnProperty('__proto__') === false`.

Comment: Thanks @ASDFGerte. I'd say I know the prototype-chain. I suspected `__proto__` was a direct property of `o1` but it came up differently on Chrome console to other direct properties I'd seen. My only question is why `o1` has a direct property called `__proto__` and why `{color: "red"} was saved under the prototype of `o2`. Does that MDN page have the answer?

Comment: As another note - i don't know if you have that misconception, but there is no issue with a property existing twice in the prototype chain: `let o = Object.create({ prop: 'value' }); Object.defineProperty(o, 'prop', { value: 'noU' }); console.log(\`Self: ${o.prop}, proto: ${Object.getPrototypeOf(o).prop}\`);`. This also gives an example for "how to explicitly add/modify a property on an object itself".

Comment: @ASDFGerte I just did a little test to see if dot notation will change object's prototype and bracket/literal notation won't. `o = {color: "red"}; Object.setPrototypeOf(o, {shape: "square"}); o.shape = "triange";` Unfortunately my dot notation only added a new 'own' property and did not change the same-named property that was stored in object's prototype. :/

Comment: You are correct, my previous statement was plain wrong. I must have been half sleeping. `__proto__` however is an "accessor property (a getter function and a setter function)".

Comment: @ASDFGerte Interesting I'm just reading up about accessor properties. So it might become clearer later. All I know right now is `.[__proto__]` adds an own property but `.__proto__` gives you the chance to target that accessor property. Maybe it'll be revealed later on that accessor properties can only be accessed through dot notation? Just guesing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

> Property definitions that do not use "colon" notation are not
> prototype mutations. They are property definitions that behave
> identically to similar definitions using any other name.

```js
let o0 = {};
console.log('o0: ' + o0.hasOwnProperty('__proto__'));
// a bare object doesnt have a property named '__proto__'

let __proto__ = {color: "red"};

let o1 = {__proto__};
// based on o0 above then, shorthand variable notation basically gets in the way of it using it 
// as accessor to the underlying prototype. Instead, the result of this is that __proto__
// becomes a property of o1 as one would expect from shorthand notation...

const newO1 = Object.create(o1);
console.log('o1: ' + o1.hasOwnProperty('__proto__'));
console.log('newO1: ' + newO1.hasOwnProperty('__proto__'));
console.log('newO1: ' + newO1.color);

let o2 = {};
Object.setPrototypeOf(o2, {color: "red"});

const newO2 = Object.create(o2);
console.log('newO2: ' + Object.keys(newO2));
console.log('newO2: ' + newO2.color);

let o3 = {__proto__: {color: 'red'}};

const newO3 = Object.create(o3);
console.log('newO3: ' + Object.keys(newO3));
console.log('newO3: ' + newO3.color);
// something about the more verbose colon notation triggers the interpreter to know that 
// you intend to mutate the prototype and so uses __proto__ as the accessor rather than
// creating __proto__ as a property
```

In this snipit:

- o0 demonstrates that bare object has no **proto** property
- o1 does not use "colon" notation.
- o3 does use "colon" notation.
- o2 makes explicit use of setPrototypeOf()
- results are the same as o3.

Comment: Thanks @DynasticSponge. Could you spell that out to me with reference to my examples? I'm not sure which ones colon notation.

Comment: I get 2 & 3 fine. If I understand what's going on with 1 (which uses 'shorthand property name notation - which is not colon mutation), `o1`s `__proto__` is not being changed. `o1` has an own property: `__proto__: {color: "red"}`. How is this possible when generally the rule is an object cannot have two keys that are named the same (I understand the last one stated overrides the previous one(s)? (I've added in at the bottom of my question a picture of what Chrome shows me `o1` is).

Comment: updated again showing o0 and adding some comments... '__proto__' isn't technically a property of an object so syntax is all there is to go on that you intend to use it to mutate the prototype... and since its use is deprecated, my guess is that they didn't update the standard to allow its use with shorthand notation in ES6

Comment: Thanks @DynasticSponge. I'm still not quite sure why `new01` is the way it is in my console (second picture in my answer). I expected: `{__proto__: {__proto__: {color: "red"}, __proto__: Object.prototype}}` Having said this, I'm aware that `__proto__` is deprecated so will look to avoid coming into these troubles.

Comment: 2nd picture.. shows newO1...  so based on discussion above o1 ends up being an object with ```__proto__``` as a property.  When you do Object.create(o1) the resultant object uses o1 as its prototype...  so new01.prototype = o1 so to get to red you have to do ```newO1.prototype.__proto__.color```

Comment: Typing in that last line gives me the error 'Cannot read property `__proto__` of undefined'